# Iterate a hbox in javafx

Tags: javafx, hbox

I have in my javafx app an **HBox** with ImageViews, now I need some way to iterate through this HBox, but I can't find out an algorithm how to do it, I have tried to do something like this:

```
Object[] stack = stackWrapp.getChildren().toArray();
```

where stack is my **HBox**, but the ImageViews in this way will be duplicated, what I don't want.  I don't know why So how can I do it..

Comment: You duplicate the **references** to the `ImageView`s, not the `ImageView`s themselfs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
for (Node child : stackWrapp.getChildren()) {
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) child;
    ...
}
```

To be on the save side you can also do a type check before the casting, just in case there are other `Nodes` in your `HBox` than only `ImageView`.

Comment: Thanks, it's that what i needed)